# ASP.NET Core MVC : complex data model reading related data

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My working project code is at https://github.com/ThomasEstes/AssetManagement

I have the following data model and I am trying to understand how to read data from the `contact` while editing `devices`.

I have the foreign key relationships and I understand conceptually how to link the data in the database, just not sure how to do it in ASP.NET.

I simply want to be able to include a list of contact.full_name on the Devices create and edit views. I want to do this with Entity Framework if possible.

[image: Data Model]

I have tried the following in my `DBContext`:

```
entity.ToTable("DeviceAssignments", "Assets");

entity.Property(e => e.AssignDate).HasColumnType("date");
entity.Property(e => e.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
            .HasColumnType("datetime");
entity.Property(e => e.Creator)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(suser_sname())");
entity.Property(e => e.Modified)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
            .HasColumnType("datetime");
entity.Property(e => e.Modifier)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(suser_sname())");
entity.Property(e => e.ReturnDate).HasColumnType("date");

entity.HasOne(d => d.Contact).WithMany(p => p.DeviceAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.ContactID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_DeviceAssignments_Contact");

entity.HasOne(d => d.Device).WithMany(p => p.DeviceAssignments)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DeviceId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_DeviceAssignments_Devices");


entity.ToTable("Devices", "Assets");

entity.Property(e => e.Comment)
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsUnicode(false);
entity.Property(e => e.Cost).HasColumnType("decimal(9, 4)");
entity.Property(e => e.Created)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
            .HasColumnType("datetime");
entity.Property(e => e.Creator)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(suser_sname())");
entity.Property(e => e.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsUnicode(false);
entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false);
entity.Property(e => e.MAC)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false);
entity.Property(e => e.Model)
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsUnicode(false);
entity.Property(e => e.Modified)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())")
            .HasColumnType("datetime");
entity.Property(e => e.Modifier)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("(suser_sname())");
entity.Property(e => e.PurchaseDate).HasColumnType("date");
entity.Property(e => e.SerialNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false);
entity.Property(e => e.Status)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsUnicode(false);

entity.HasOne(d => d.DeviceCategory).WithMany(p => p.Devices)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DeviceCategoryId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Devices_DeviceCategories");

entity.HasOne(d => d.DeviceLocation).WithMany(p => p.Devices)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DeviceLocationId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Devices_DeviceLocations");
```

`DevicesController`:

```
// GET: Devices/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || _context.Devices == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var devices = await _context.Devices.FindAsync(id);

    if (devices == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    ViewData["DeviceCategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.DeviceCategories, "DeviceCategoryId", "DeviceCategoryName", devices.DeviceCategoryId);
    ViewData["DeviceLocationId"] = new SelectList(_context.DeviceLocations, "DeviceLocationId", "DeviceLocationName", devices.DeviceLocationId);            

    return View(devices);
}
```

`Edit.cshtml`:

```
@model QsccDevAlpha.Models.Devices

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Devices</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="DeviceId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DeviceCategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DeviceCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DeviceCategoryId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="DeviceCategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DeviceLocationId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DeviceLocationId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DeviceLocationId"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="DeviceLocationId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SerialNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="SerialNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SerialNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PurchaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PurchaseDate" asp-format="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PurchaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="InvoiceNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="InvoiceNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="InvoiceNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MAC" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="MAC" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="MAC" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Model" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Model" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Model" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Status" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Status" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Status" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Cost" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Cost" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Cost" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Comment" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Comment" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using DTO's?

Comment: @Pieterjan I am not familiar with DTOs or how I would use them in this instance. Can you give me an example? I am very new to ASP.net and MVC, I am self-taught so any examples or demos would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Data Access Layer](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/tree/master/MintPlayer.Data) - [Web Application](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/tree/master/MintPlayer.Web) - only use DTOs in your web application - in the repository you can lookup the entity and update only the properties that matter

Comment: I think you can create a `ModelDto` containing both `contact` and `devices`: `public class ModelDto{public contact contact { get; set; } public devices devices { get; set; }}`. And then use this `ModelDto` in your view. The attributes in your view are `@Model.contact .xx`, `@Model.devices.xx`...

Comment: @Pieterjan I have added my github repo. Would you be will to show me an example of DTO with my given code?

Comment: Questions stating "I want to do X" without explaining the exact problem in trying to do X don't work well on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've currently achieved this in other ways. But if you want to display the data of two models in one view, DTO is a very common choice.

Take `Create` as an example:

You can create a ViewModel contains both `Devices` and `Contacts`:

```
public class DevicesDTO
{
    public Devices DevicesClass { get; set; }
    public Contacts ContactsClass { get; set; }
}
```

Then your `Create.cshtml` can be this:

```
@model AssetsManagement.Models.DevicesDTO

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Devices</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DevicesClass.DeviceCategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.DevicesClass.DeviceCategoryId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DeviceCategoryId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DevicesClass.DeviceLocationId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.DevicesClass.DeviceLocationId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DeviceLocationId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DevicesClass.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.DevicesClass.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.DevicesClass.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.DevicesClass.SerialNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.DevicesClass.SerialNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.DevicesClass.SerialNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ContactsClass.ContactId" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.ContactsClass.ContactId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ContactsClass.ContactId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.ContactsClass.FullName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.ContactsClass.FullName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ContactsClass.FullName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.ContactsClass.FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.ContactsClass.FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ContactsClass.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.ContactsClass.LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="@Model.ContactsClass.LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.ContactsClass.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}
```

where you can use properties of both `Devices` and `Contacts`.

`Create`'s post method can be changed to:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(DevicesDTO devices)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(devices.DevicesClass);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["DeviceCategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.DeviceCategories, "DeviceCategoryId", "DeviceCategoryName", devices.DevicesClass.DeviceCategoryId);
    ViewData["DeviceLocationId"] = new SelectList(_context.DeviceLocations, "DeviceLocationId", "DeviceLocationName", devices.DevicesClass.DeviceLocationId);
    return View(devices);
}
```

At the same time, you need to change some virtual properties of `Devices` and `Contacts` to nullable types, otherwise it will fail model verification:

```
public class Devices
{
    [Key]
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }
    public int DeviceCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? DeviceLocationId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceCategories? DeviceCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceLocations? DeviceLocation { get; set; }
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contacts>? Contacts { get; set; }
    public List<DeviceAssignments>? DeviceAssignments { get; set; }
}
public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Devices>? Devices { get; set; }
    public List<DeviceAssignments>? DeviceAssignments { get; set; }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Of course, personally I prefer to use `ViewData` like yours to pass if using `SelectList`.

Hope this can help you.